# Polynomials with Integer Coefficients and irrational roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, irrational-numbers

Is there a polynomial with integer coefficients which has √2 +√7 ￼ as a root?

Comment: What is that  ￼ ?

Comment: I suppose you want just this one root (no plural)

Answer (score 8):

$$x=\sqrt2+\sqrt7$$
$$x^2=9+2\sqrt{14}$$
$$(x^2-9)^2-56=0$$

Answer (score 7):

To give a non-constructive but general algebraic answer:

The numbers $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are [algebraic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). As the algebraic numbers form a field, the number $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ is algebraic, too. Thus there is a polynomial with rational coefficients which has $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ as root. Now multiply by the common divisor to obtain a polynomial with integer coefficients.

If you require the polynomial to be [monic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial), you are asking whether $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ is an [algebraic integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer). Here, too, it is easy to see that both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are algebraic integers and as the algebraic integers form a ring, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7}$ is an algebraic integer.

Answer (score 6):

$$
x = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{7} \\ (x-\sqrt{2})^2=7 \\ x^2-2\sqrt{2}x+2=7 \\ x^2-5=2\sqrt{2}x \\ (x^2-5)^2=8x^2 \\ x^4-18x^2+25=0
$$